# After uploading image in Cloudinary through React js unable to get response

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mern, cloudinary

After using the Api it should return a response once the the image is uploaded.

But even though the image is uploaded i am not getting any rsponse through the api.

```
if (pic.type === "image/jpeg" || pic.type === "image/png") {
      const data = new FormData();
      data.append("file", pic)
      data.append("upload_preset", "baatchitapp")
      data.append("cloud_name", "******")
      fetch("https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/******/image/upload", {
        method: "post",
        body: data,
      })
        .then((res) => {
          res.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
          console.log(data);
          // setPic(data.url.toString());
          setLoading(false);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log("Error: ",err);
          setLoading(false);
        });
    }
```

Comment: It's working fine for me. I am getting a response from the API URL. I can see the image being uploaded and the response shows the URL of the image.

Comment: i know the code is correct but still i am getting "undefined" in my console

Comment: I know what the issue is Rahul. You are NOT doing the `res.json()` correctly. You are not returning anything in your `.then` promise. The rest of your code is fine. Change to this `.then((res) => res.json()).then(data => { console.log(data);})` - you will see response in your console after image being uploaded.

Comment: Thanks it worked, I can't believe due to such a small thing I waste hours to solve it, Thank you very much

Comment: No worries Rahul. I am glad I was able to help. Enjoy. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a return before res.json();

```
.then((res) => {
          return res.json();
        })
```